# Error installing from GitHub using pip on Windows

Tags: python, github, pip, ipython, nltk

I am on a Windows machine and I want to install a Python module from GitHub using pip directly from IPython.

The simplest command that seems it should work is:

```
!pip install https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer.git
```

I have also tried:

```
!pip install https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer.git#egg=nltk-trainer
```

I've used variants including `-vvv`, etc.

However, I'm getting the following error.  Why?

`Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\timo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-183bwemw\nltk-trainer`

Comment: What documentation have you followed? Perhaps https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow that.  Being a new user, I couldn't list all the things I tried since the commands are seen as web links and I'm limited to 2.  I had tried: git+https://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject

Comment: I had tried '!pip install -e git+https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer.git#egg=nltk-trainer' both with and without the -e.  I get the error "cannot find git".

Comment: Problem was resolved by installing git.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer and download the project zip file. extract the zip file and put it somewhere in your computer.
2. open command prompt in windows and go inside the folder that you extracted earlier(you must be in the folder that has setup.py file in it).
3. enter the following command: python setup.py install 
   python tries to install nltk-trainer . during installation some other dependency might be installed too. you need numpy and scipy to be installed. if any problem happened during installation of numpy or scipy try installing them manually first by using `pip install numpy` and `pip install scipy`

if you can't install numpy and scipy using pip command use the following link:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

this site has compiled version of these libraries ( and other libraries if you need to install them too) you can download `.whl` file that is based on your python version and os architecture and install them using `pip install  filename.whl` command ( you need to be in the folder that your whl file is) for example for python3.4 and 64bit operating system you may download `scipy‑0.16.0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl` file.